# Multiple authentication methods (Office 365 OR Facebook/Google/Twitter) in a ASP.Net Core application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have setup ASP.NET Core applications to allow authentication via Office 365 before (by using the Change Authentication screen during project setup).

I would like to setup ASP.NET Core application that would allow internal users to authenticate using their Office 365 account but external users would authenticate with their OpenAuth (Facebook, Google, Twitter, etc.) account.

How do I go about setting up this multiple-authentication method?   I searched StackOverflow and Google and came up empty.

Comment: Are you trying to hide some auth methods from some users? Or are you just trying to enable all of them in the same app? The latter is easy.

Comment: https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html, then add OpenIdConnect with your O365 settings.

Comment: @Tratcher Thanks.  I have it currently setup with "Work and School Accounts" instead of "Individual User Accounts". Do you know if it's possible to change authentication type after project is created?  Or do I need to recreate and migrate my code over?

Comment: It can be done, but it's a lot more work to add multiple auth types to the Work & School template than it is to add OpenIdConnect to the Individual auth template. The Individual auth template is already set up to handle multiple auth types.

Comment: Can you make your answer with a like an answer instead of a comment, so I can give you credit for awesomeness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are you trying to enable all of them in the same app then start here:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/sociallogins.html, then add OpenIdConnect with your O365 settings.